# I have a program, worked on win95 and i did not compile on winXP

Tags: c, compiler-construction, header-files

i have a program and work on win95 old machine. I want to work on win xp and want to be executed this program on xp. Application use some hardware (two card which is plugged in isa slot). I have application soruce code but, codes not support on xp. For example, graphics.h, eg_proto.h,color.h, wg_var.h header files don't have anywhere on modern compiler. I have turbo c 1.0 compiler but not support me for this situation.

So, what can i do about this situation? Would you suggest anythings about?

Some header files from source code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <color.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <alloc.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <dir.h>
#include <process.h>  
#include <eg_proto.h>
#include <pchrt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dw.h>
#include <dwdata.h>
#include <wdh.h>
```

I dont know anything about some header file. for example, dw.h, dwdata.h, wdh.h. I didnt found any description about this header file.

Edit:
My compiler is Turbo C 2.01

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQFnI.jpg

Comment: You require professional help to do the code conversion... It is not easy to figure out what your system does from just looking at the headers.

Comment: @aix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Turbo_C I'm quite amazed that he's got a tool from 1987..

Comment: @aix no it's old MFC foundation class stuff...

Comment: @AhmedMasud: The author said that he's got a Turbo C 1.0 compiler..

Comment: i am sorry. i have 2.0 version. i am editing it from question.

Comment: You may be in trouble. This program's intended to talk to ISA hardware, right? Unfortunately, unlike Windows 95, Windows XP is an NT based operating system and isn't based on DOS, and while it's got pretty good DOS emulation, it's not complete. One of the things it won't let you do is talk directly to hardware. It _might_ be possible to persuade it to lift the security restrictions for certain processes, but I don't know about that. You may need to write an NT kernel driver for the hardware, and that's really not nice. You'll have to find someone how knows, I'm afraid.

Comment: it is impossible with me. Maybe, i have to find someone as you said. Lastly, I will try to create virtual (win95 or win98) machine and compile or run on the virtual machine and share some file with winXP to report their datas. Maybe, i can be successful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same compiler on both systems, it is almost certain that the missing headers are not part of the compiler package. They are certainly not part of the OS since your compiler predates both operating systems.

I see two main possibilities:

1. These headers are part of your project and are not being found due an error in the build process.
2. These headers are part of some third-party libraries that you have installed in one environment and not the other.

Either way, you need to find them and either fix your build settings, or copy the headers across from the old system to the new one.

Comment: i dont compile the system on win95. Executable application is running on win95. I did not try to compile on win95. I tried to compile on winxp.